# Procedure returning PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EOF" when expecting

Tags: plsql, procedure, pls-00103

I'm new to PL/SQL, doing a homework question where I need to write a procedure that returns an error message based on day of week/time but I am stuck on a basic thing before I get to that point:

I have written the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE
SECURE_IT
(p_weekday NUMBER,
 p_currtime TIME)
IS
BEGIN
select to_char(current_timestamp,'D')
  , to_char(current_timestamp,'HH24:MI') 
into p_weekday, p_currtime 
from dual;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_weekday,p_currtime);
END;
```

I think all of my ;'s are all in place, can't see any difference between this, code in the book, and code I've found online yet still it returns this error:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the 
following: ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> 
current delete exists prior <a single-quoted SQL string> The symbol ";" 
was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.
```

I tried changing END; to END SECURE_IT; in hopes that it would fix something (all I could think of) but can't see what's wrong. Could someone help me with this?

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: Unfortunately the error message in this case doesn't help you. There are two problems: (1) `TIME` is not a valid datatype unless you have defined it yourself; (2) `DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line` only accepts one parameter.

Comment: Another issue is that your parameters use the default `IN` mode, but your procedure is trying to assign new values to them - this won't be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of mistakes in your procedure

1. `TIME` datatype (In PL/SQL there is no such datatype see [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG004), Alternatively, you can pass datetime data types: DATE, TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, and TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE)
   You can extract time part using many options. For example:

   ```
   SELECT TO_CHAR(p_currDateTime, 'HH24:MI:SS') into p_currtime FROM DUAL;
   ```
2. You are trying to update `p_weekday` & `p_currtime` which are IN parameters. These parameters are used to pass value to the procedure, and not to return ones.
3. `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` takes only one parameter, so instead of `,` you can concatenate the two values like this: `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_weekday||'-'||p_currtime);`

It would help a great deal if it is not clear what are you trying to achieve by this procedure

Answer (score 0):

Basically what i can see here is you need to print some value out od procedure as a part of your homework. But using dbms_output will not do any good. You need to make these as OUT param to use these values any where.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SECURE_IT(
        p_weekday OUT VARCHAR2,
        p_currtime OUT VARCHAR2)
    IS
    BEGIN
      p_weekday := TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'D');
      p_currtime:= TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'HH24:MI');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_weekday||' '||p_currtime);
    END;

-----------------------------EXECUTE--------------------------------------------

var week VARChaR2(100);
var curtime VARChaR2(100);

EXEC SECURE_IT(:week,:curtime);

print week;
print curtime;

-------------------------------OUTPUT--------------------------------------------

WEEK
-
6

CURTIME
-----
06:12

-------------------------------OUTPUT----------------------------------------------
```